# How to get the records based on the given dates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to count the number of days and `Reading` based on the given two dates from the below table. I'm little experienced in SQL but not getting any clue to solve this can any of you please help me out.

```
Create Table Meter_Reading(ID(int),From_Date (Datetime), To_Date(Datetime), Reading (int))

    INSERT INTO Meter_Reading VALUES (1, '2015-05-15', '2015-06-14',20);
    INSERT INTO Meter_Reading VALUES (2, '2015-06-15', '2015-07-17',30);
    INSERT INTO Meter_Reading VALUES (3, '2015-07-18', '2013-08-11',10);

    Declare @StartDT Datetime,@EndDT Datetime

    SET @STARTDT = '2015-05-01'
    SET @ENDDT  = '2015-06-30'

    select ID  
          ,case when From_Date >= @StartDT THEN DATEDIFF(d,@StartDT,From_Date)
                    ELSE DATEDIFF(d,TO_Date,@ENDDT) end 'Days'
          ,Reading
    FROM Meter_Reading
    WHERE (From_Date <= @ENDDT
            and TO_Date >= @STARTDT)   

    Output with the above logic:
     1  14  20
     2  45  30

    Output Expected:
     1  31  20
     2  16  30
```

Comment: 2015-05-15 to 2015-06-14 is more than 14 days.  Are you saying only count weekdays? Exclude holidays? Need more details on how you get the number of days.

Comment: @TTeeple Thanks for the quick response. 

Let's say here I'm passing 2015-06-01 and 2015-06-30. If one of these dates are there in any record of the above table then I want to get the number of days till To_date (column) value in that specific record and Qty as well. so first 14 days are there in first record then next 16 days are there in next record.

Comment: Does it matter if both dates that are passed in are in the same range?

Comment: @TTeeple  No that shouldn't be a problem

Comment: And I'm trying to include holidays as well.

Comment: @SandeepSangshetty What if you pasted the dates 2015-05-01 and 2015-06-30

Comment: @HolmesIV 
Based on your query and the above data I will get only 15+14 days data from first record then remaining 16 days data from next record.

Comment: @SandeepSangshetty maybe you can just show some basic algebra, because i see no way you can get your Expected output\

Comment: @HolmesIV Sorry for the confusion. can you now see my expected output in my updated question details

Comment: @SandeepSangshetty i just see no possible math to give a 31 for the output of number 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need some complicated date logic, something like this:

```
select t.*,
       datediff(day, (case when t.from_date < @StartDate then @StartDate else t.from_date and),
                (case when t.to_date > @EndDate then @EndDate else t.to_date end)
               ) + 1 as diff
from table t
where t.from_date <= @EndDate and t.to_date >= @StartDate
```

Comment: Thank you. Finally I could able solve my issue with your logic.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will give you what you want.

```
Declare @StartDT DATE
        ,@EndDT DaTE

SET @STARTDT = '2015-05-01'
SET @ENDDT  = '2015-06-30'


select PRODUCT_ID   
        ,case when From_Date >= @StartDT THEN DATEDIFF(d,@StartDT,From_Date)
                ELSE DATEDIFF(d,TO_DATE,@ENDDT) end 'DATEDIF'
FROM TABLEName
WHERE (FROM_DATE <= @ENDDT
        and TO_DATE >= @STartDT )
```

Comment: What is FROM_DATE is before @STARTDT and TO_DATE is after @ENDDT?

Comment: @Holmes IV , Updated my table and tried something like this but not getting what I'm looking for.

Comment: I have updated my question with your logic tried please let me know if I'm missing something. And I changed my table and some other things in the updated question

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable suggestions, finally I could able to resolve this issue with help of @Gordon Linoff logic